# Are cudaMemcpy and cublas blocking in peer-to-peer mode?

Tags: cuda, cublas, multi-gpu

I would like to copy memory between two CUDA devices (with UVA support) by calling `cudaMemcpy`. I was wondering if the call is synchronous with respect to the host? I'm aware that `cudaMemcpy` within the same device is asynchronous, but what about the copy between different devices? Do I need to call `cudaDeviceSynchronize` to make sure that copying has finished, or its ensured automatically?

I also have a similar question about cublas. I'd like to add a vector stored on one device to the vector stored on another, so I'm calling `cublasSaxpy` for that. Will it block the host until the operation is finished, or I need to synchronize explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm aware that cudaMemcpy within the same device is asynchronous

The documentation says, "This function exhibits synchronous behavior for **most** use cases." (my emphasis). However, though `cudaMemcpy()` does exhibit asynchronous behavior in some corner cases, those same corner cases have behavior that negates that behavior. The end result is that you can rely  on `cudaMemcpy()` being synchronous, also when doing peer-to-peer copies.

If you need asynchronous behavior, you should call `cudaMemcpyAsync()`.

The CUBLAS API is asynchronous for the most part, including `cublasSaxpy`. The exception is some of the calls that return scalars.

Comment: Actually, [NVIDIA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#concurrent-execution-host-device) says `Memory copies between two addresses to the same device memory;` is asynchronous. But in my case I'm doing peer-to-peer copy, so I assume it's synchronous.  
  
`The CUBLAS API is asynchronous for the most part, including cublasSaxpy`
Even when one the arguments is stored on another device?

Comment: @simon, thank you for the correction. Odd that that the programming guide has more information about this than the reference. That certainly sounds like it could trip someone up. About `cublasSaxpy` with arguments stored on another device, I don't know. Will that actually work? If it does, you could find out by timing your calls. Just compare the timing of `cublasSaxpy` alone and one together with a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`.